# How to remove minus and plus sign duplicates via Talend job?

Tags: java, etl, talend

I have loaded local file into talend process and need to do below condition this file data

Below my csv file data showing like

```
NO,DATE,MARK
123,2015-03-01,200    
123,2015-03-01,-200    
123,2015-03-01,200    
123,2015-03-01,200 
125,2016-01-01,80
```

Here above `"200"` and `"-200"` two values availed. if I have `-200` 
I need to remove corresponding `+200` value after that If I have same `NO,DATE,MARK` then I need to remove duplicates two

`" 123,2015-03-01,200"," 123,2015-03-01,200" = " 123,2015-03-01,200"`

Finally my result should come like below

```
 NO,DATE,MARK
 123,2015-03-01,200
 125,2016-01-01,80
```

After that I need to some `200 + 80 =  125,2016-01-01,280`. How to do above process using talend job.

Comment: Your example seems off: the final 2 rows have different numbers, are you sure they'd need to be added? That said, I'd suggest you just do the same as you'd do with those last 2 rows: add them all up in order and send the result whereever you need to send it to (can't tell you how to do that in Talend but I doubt that problem is that special that you'd have special support for it).

Comment: Hi, Help me few things@Thomas

Comment: What did _you_ try? How would _you_ process the data if you were the computer (i.e. think of what limited information the computer has and only use that along with basic rules)?

Answer (score 0):

Step by step, we can start by removing this:

```
123,2015-03-01,200    
123,2015-03-01,-200
```

we can do it by summing `MARK` after grouping by `NO` and `DATE` by using the talend compoenet `tAggregateRow`. After, we will get :

```
123,2015-03-01,0
```

Now we can use the component `tFilterRow` to remove all rows having `MARK == 0`, and the component `tUniqRow` to remove duplicated rows.

The last step is to get the sum of `MARK` using `tAggregateRow` and store it in a context variable, then get the greatest `NO` and the latest `DATE` by using the component `tSortRow` and then get only that row using `tSampleRow`. We can affect the sum of `MARK`.